# Get image name when running pixel-wise max() in Image Collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, max

I have multiple aligned rasters, one for each crop type, where values range from 0 to 100 (%). I'm trying to produce a class raster, where each pixel is assigned to only one crop type.
I want to assume that a pixel belongs to a crop type class when that particular crop presented the highest value (%) in its own raster.

I'm thinking I should put all images in a single ImageCollection and run a .max() method in order to get the maximum pixel value from any of the crop rasters. But how do I know from which particular image that pixel value came?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ee.Reducer.max`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-max) takes a `numInputs` argument that can be used to copy additional values that correspond with the maximum of the first band. If you add a `class` band to each crop image, combine them into a collection, and use a max reducer with `numInputs: 2`, the output will be a single image with one band for the maximum probability of all crops and another band for the associated crop class.

Here's a [quick demo](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b2065699aa693e790ff8d6a126c347aa) with random dummy data:

```js
// Create dummy crop probability images
var crop1 = ee.Image.random(1);
var crop2 = ee.Image.random(2);
var crop3 = ee.Image.random(3);

// Add a "class" band to each image
crop1 = crop1.addBands(ee.Image.constant(1).uint8());
crop2 = crop2.addBands(ee.Image.constant(2).uint8());
crop3 = crop3.addBands(ee.Image.constant(3).uint8());

// Collect all of the crop images into a single collection
var crop_probs = ee.ImageCollection([crop1, crop2, crop3]);

// Reduce the collection with `numImputs: 2` to include the crop class with the max probability
var crop_class = crop_probs.reduce(ee.Reducer.max({numInputs: 2})).rename(["prob", "class"]);
Map.addLayer(crop_class, {min: 1, max: 3, bands: ["class"]}, "Crop class")
```

Comment: great solution! I ended up doing something very similar, but using qualityMosaic instead of max, but I like your solution better :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is what I ended up doing. I added the class code as a property to each raster file upon upload, so it could be fetched by a function that adds a band with that value as a constant. Then used qualityMosaic to use the probability band as a quality band.

```
// CREATING A CROP CLASS RASTER

var maize = ee.Image.random(1);
var soy = ee.Image.random(2);
var rice = ee.Image.random(3);
var geoglam = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([maize, soy, rice]);

var addClass = function(img){
  // MAKE A BAND FOR STORING THE CROP CLASS
  var cropBand = ee.Image.constant(img.get('cropclass')).toLong().rename('cropclass');
  img = img.addBands(cropBand);
  return img;
};

// maping the whole collection using function
var with_class = geoglam.map(addClass);

//A quality mosaic will take the pixel with the highest value from the quality band (in this case the % coverage)
var geoglamcrop  = with_class.qualityMosaic('b1');
```